# Is it possible to change Solr UniqueKey type "String " to other Types in Apache Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, solr6

Is it possible to change the UniqueKey-tag in  schema.xml from String to Int or Long? 
My Primary key in my application is of type Long - so it's not favorable to get a Solr-response of type string.. So if possible: how can it be done?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Start by referering the `<uniqueKey>`-tag in schema.xml/managed-schema to a desired name which describes the key well. Let's call this name "id".

You then need a `<field>`-tag with the parameter `name="id"` - so that `<uniqueKey>` is refering to a defined field. The type of the field is easy to adjust by altering the "type"-parameter - in this case either to float or int.

Resources on defining fields: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Defining+Fields

Comment: We cannot directly change the Type in schema.xml/managed-schema..if We do then Will get following exception ":org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error initializing QueryElevationComponent."  please refer following link for more Info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420972/declaring-unique-key-as-int-in-solr-results-in-error..                                                                   Apart from this Any other way or solution to Change the Type of <uniqueKey>-tag

Comment: Another approach might be to use a copy field and set the desired type on that field.